# Hibernate Soft Deletion Still deleting my Record

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hibernate-mapping, soft-delete

I'm trying to implement soft deletion using Hibernate but for some reason my record still gets deleted. Anyone mind taking a look.

```
public class SoftDeleteEventListener extends DefaultDeleteEventListener {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
@Override
public void onDelete(DeleteEvent event, Set transientEntities) throws HibernateException {
    Object dbEntity = event.getObject();

    if (dbEntity instanceof Entity) 
    {
        ((Entity)dbEntity).setDeleted(true);
        ((Entity)dbEntity).setDeletedOn(new Date());

        EntityPersister persister = event.getSession().getEntityPersister( event.getEntityName(), dbEntity);
        EntityEntry entityEntry = event.getSession().getPersistenceContext().getEntry(dbEntity);

        cascadeBeforeDelete(event.getSession(), persister, dbEntity, entityEntry, transientEntities);
        cascadeAfterDelete(event.getSession(), persister, dbEntity, transientEntities);
    } else {
        super.onDelete(event, transientEntities);
    }
}
```

}

and this is how i am registering my session / listener

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure();
        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder ssrb = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(ssrb.build());

        EventListenerRegistry registry = ((SessionFactoryImpl)sessionFactory).getServiceRegistry().getService(
        EventListenerRegistry.class);
        registry.getEventListenerGroup(EventType.DELETE).appendListener(new SoftDeleteEventListener());
```

Comment: What do you mean with soft deletion?

Comment: soft deletion is where I update the record to mark is as deleted which is represented in line 

        ((Entity)dbEntity).setDeleted(true);
        ((Entity)dbEntity).setDeletedOn(new Date());

Comment: Basically marks the record as deleted instead of physically deleting the record

Comment: Why don't you add a column marking whether a record is soft deleted or not ?

Comment: That's what I did all all objects which will be saved to the database extend an Entity class which contains 2 field deleted / deleted_on which mark the record as deleted.

what i want to do is override hibernate delete method so that instead of deleting the record if it is of type Entity it should mark it as deleted

Answer (score 1):

To fix this issue:

1. You need to define a `deleted` column
2. And, you need to annotate the entity with

   ```
    @SQLDelete(sql="UPDATE customer SET deleted = true WHERE id = ?")
   ```

This is much more simple than using a Hibernate Interceptor.

I'd try a simpler version:

```
if (dbEntity instanceof Entity) 
{
    ((Entity)dbEntity).setDeleted(true);
    ((Entity)dbEntity).setDeletedOn(new Date());

    event.getSession().mergedbEntity
} else {
    super.onDelete(event, transientEntities);
}
```

Comment: So all objects inherit from an Entity class which does not specify and id field, its left up to the child classes to implement the id.

your solution would entail that I add @SQLDelete to all my child classes which is not something i want to do ...

i would rather listen on the delete event check if the object is extending the entity object and if it is just update the deleted fields

the code like this should be more maintainable

Comment: That's a way to do it too. You can check if the entity implements a soft deletable interface and apply the logic.

Comment: Can't get it to work though in my question I sampled my code any idea what's wrong with it?

Comment: But that way it will not override hibernate default delete method